# What is the expectation of the largest eigenvalue of a Wishart distributed matrix?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $\mathcal{S}_{++}^d$ denote the space of (symmetric) positive definite matrices of size $d \times d$, where $d\in \mathbb{N}$ is given.
The density function of the $\mathrm{Wishart}_d(\nu,\mathbb{M})$ distribution is defined by
\begin{equation}\label{eq:Wishart.density}
    f_{\nu,\mathbb{M}}(\mathbb{X}) = \frac{|\mathbb{X}|^{\nu/2 - (d + 1)/2} \exp\big(-\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}(\mathbb{M}^{-1} \mathbb{X})\big)}{|2 \, \mathbb{M}|^{\nu/2} \pi^{d(d-1)/4} \prod_{i=1}^d \Gamma\Big(\frac{\nu}{2} - \frac{i - 1}{2}\Big)}, \quad \mathbb{X}\in \mathcal{S}_{++}^d,
\end{equation}
where $\nu > d - 1$ is the number of degrees of freedom, and $\mathbb{M}\in \mathcal{S}_{++}^d$ is the scale matrix.

If $\mathbb{S} \sim \mathrm{Wishart}_d(\nu,\mathbb{M})$ and $\lambda_{\mathrm{max}}(\mathbb{S})$ is the largest eigenvalue of $\mathbb{S}$, then what is $\mathbb{E}[\lambda_{\mathrm{max}}(\mathbb{S})]$ ?

I can't find any reference with a clear answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

This reference seems to have a pretty clear answer:

*Chiani, Marco*, [**Distribution of the largest eigenvalue for real Wishart and Gaussian random matrices and a simple approximation for the Tracy-Widom distribution**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jmva.2014.04.002), J. Multivariate Anal. 129, 69-81 (2014). [ZBL1359.60013](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1359.60013).

Comment: which equation ?
because Sections  2.1 and 2.2 are about the uncorrelated Wishart, not the general case.

Comment: @FrédéricOuimet You want arbitrary covariance?  For real Wishart?

Comment: yes, real Wishart, arbitrary $\nu$ and scale matrix M. The result can be asymptotic in $\nu$, but otherwise, i need the general case